# Modify and add extension to filenames with shell script in a file

Tags: shell

I have a list of filenames contained in a file names "file.txt" which is like this :

```
filename1 some_block_of_text
filename2 some_block_of_text 
filename3 some_block_of_text 
filename4 some_block_of_text 
...
```

All I want to do is to parse this file and change all the filenames with adding extension ".ext" so that my file be like this :

```
filename1.ext 
filename2.ext
filename3.ext 
filename4.ext 
...
```

The file which contains the filenames is passed as argument so the command should be :
./my_script.sh file.txt

I'm novice with that, should I go for something like this :

```
#!usr/bin/bash

for filename in $1 :
    rename -s /old_filename/new_file_name
```

?

Thank you in advance for your help guys

Comment: Welcome to SO. kudos for sharing your efforts in your question. could you please edit your samples of file name from `filename1 some_block_of_text` to some more meaningful that will give us better understanding of samples, thank you.

Comment: These could be like this :

filename1  NLP 005 896 2102

or : filename2 26 569 8467 120

these could be alphanumerical caracters after the filename itself but it is always separated with a space and I want to get rid of everything which is after this space and add ".ext" to the name "filename1" and "filename2" etc..

Comment: Please clarify: According to your tag (_shell_), you are looking for a POSIX shell solution, but the example code you posted, suggests that you would like to have one in bash. Edit the tags and/or write explicitly in your question, what kind of shell the code is supposed to run.

Comment: Are you trying to edit your original file, or actually rename the files *listed* in the original file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, attempts; please try following code. Using `awk` here to print 1st column with .ext format.

```
cat script.bash
awk '{print $1".ext"}' "$1"
```

***Explanation:*** Simply printing 1st column of each line adding `.ext` string to it.

Comment: You forgot to use `file.txt`. You can't use `filename*`, because the file pattern is not known statically, so you have to use a `while read` loop.

Comment: @user1934428, sorry I didn't get it, could you please do give me details on what I could improve, thank you.

Comment: The OP says that the list of filenames to be renamed is stored in a file named `file.txt`, so this has to be processed.

Comment: I tried a different approach to the task. Perhaps you could have a look and with your sharp eye find a possible mistake in it?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, the echo command returns nothing :(
Ow I didn't see the previous comments :)

Comment: @BJB, could you please confirm you are passing right file name in place of `Input_file` in my code?

Comment: @BJB, yes please try my latest code once.

Comment: But I don't understand. If the file "file.txt" which contains the filenames is passed as an argument like this : "./script.sh filenames.txt", shouldn't we use "$1" in the code ?
Then I don't fully understand the "while read" loop.. Is it reading line by line ? So why it is the same variable name "file" which is used in the "while read file" and in the lines themselves" ?

Comment: @BJB, yes pass it like `done < "$1"` if you are passing it as an argument, let me know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: @BJB, could you please do let me know if solution has worked for you? thank you.

Comment: I wrote :

`   #!/bin/bash
    filename=$1
    while read file
    do
        echo "$file ${file%% *}.ext"
    done < $filename
`
and it worked well, it prints for each file of each line :

filename other_stuff_like_numbers filename.ext, but when I changed into : `mv "$file" "${file%% *}.ext"` I get the error "impossible to evaluate blabla"

Comment: @BJB, try changing mv line to `mv --"$file" "${file%% *}.ext"` once? in 2nd code of mine and let me know if that helps you?

Comment: Not recognized target.. Are you sure mv command is appropriate here ?

Comment: @BJB, for renaming files yes its best command, I have tested it with your shown samples files and it worked fine for me, I hope you are running exact code like posted in 2nd solution like: `while read file
do
  if [[ "${file%% *}" !=  "$file" ]]
  then
       mv "$file" "${file%% *}.ext"
  fi
done < "Input_file"` where Input_file is your actual file name here.

Comment: @BJB, if my code is working with your small edit, then you can edit my answer and I will approve it then, cheers.

Comment: `#!/bin/bash`
`while read file`
`do`
 ` if [[ "${file%% *}" !=  "$file" ]]`
  `then`
       `mv "$file" "${file%% *}.ext"`
  `fi`
`done < $1`

Comment: @BJB, is this command working for you now? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: I tried it with the following file "filenames" : https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=21/26/57fh.jpg

and I get the following error : https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=21/26/v0t2.jpg

(I'm french) It says "Impossible to evaluate blabla : No file or folder of this type"

Comment: @BJB, ok so `zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=21/26/v0t2.jpg` file should be renamed to which file? My answer assumes(as per your samples) that there was space after 1st name from where you want to cut the name, let me know.

Comment: filename is $1, it's the file which contains the list of filenames followed by alphanumerical caracters... (name of files are alkyl, abel etc...)

If I just make "echo" it displays me "alkyl alphanumerical caracters alkyl.ext" so it works well  but "mv" gets me the error I've pointed out

Comment: @BJB, could you please make sure `mv "$file" "${file%% *}.ext"` line is copied from answer as it is?

Comment: If I do :

while read file_name; do echo "mv $file_name ${file_name%% *}.ext"; done < $1

and run the command ./script.sh filenames, it gets me : https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=21/26/sw9h.jpg

so it seems to work

Comment: I think maybe you didn't understand what I want to do. Maybe mv does not work because the list of files are not in the directory, the name of the files only exist in the file "filenames" all I want to do is replace for example "abel 00236 10455 blabla" by abel.ext and write it in the file "filenames" instead of the previous name "abel 00236 blabla"

Comment: @BJB, oh ok you don't want to rename actual files :) you want to change it in file(where all file names are present), correct?

Comment: absolutely. I should have precised "and replace it in the file "filename" itself.

Comment: @BJB, If this is the case you want to read file which has all entries and you only want to change entries of files NOT actual files renaming then try following command in your script, `awk '{print $1".ext"}' "$1"` where $1 is your Input_file name passed to script, that should print the file names as per line.

Comment: yes, but without the alphanumerical caracters ? I want filename1 00023 blabla --> filename1.ext

Comment: @BJB, what `awk '{print $1".ext"}' "$1"` command is giving as of now?

Comment: OMG it worked perfectly... but how does it work ?, it had eluded all stuff after the filenames ?
Hum ok the $1 between the {} means the first argument of the line..

Comment: Ok finally I managed oof thank you very much for your support

Comment: But it actually prints the way I wanted in the terminal but how to finally replace it in the file itself ?

Comment: @BJB, change it like: `awk '{print $1".ext"}' "$1" > temp && mv temp "$1"` let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Since your filenames, by construction, are guaranteed not having a space or a newline in them, you could do a

```
cut -f 1 -d ' ' file.txt|xargs -L 1 -I {} -t mv -v {} {}.ext
```

The `cut` generates the list of filenames, and the `xargs -L 1` applies them one by one to the `mv` command.

*Warning*: I did not test the command, so prepend the `mv` my an `echo` for doing a dry run, before actually running the command.